# Why does computing g^a * g^{-a} with the PBC library result in zero?

Tags: pairings

My example code is as follows:

```
 /*
 *  Example 1
 *  1) Calculate g^a
 *  2) calculate g^{-a}
 *  3) multiply g^a * g^{-a}
 *
 */
```

**Note:** here `pub->p` is a type A pairing.

```
element_t g, gA,gInverseA, a;

element_init_G1(g,pub->p);
element_init_G1(gA,pub->p);
element_init_G1(gInverseA,pub->p);

element_init_Zr(a,pub->p);

element_random(g); 
element_random(a);

element_pow_zn(gA,a);
element_invert(gInverseA,gA);

element_mul(gInverseA,gInverseA,gA); 
element_printf("\nValue %B",gInverseA);
```

Why does it output zero?

Comment: First the obvious: have you checked that `element_mul` is designed to allow its result to be one of its arguments? Or tried to setup a specific result variable?

Comment: Also, doesn't element_pow_zn take three parameters?